# Alternative to Automation of office tools on server

Tags: c#

I have an application which creates word, excel and powerpoint applications, store them and retrieve them, make changes in the documents online and upload documents. But all these features run only in visual studio. When I host the program on IIS, this automation is not possible as Microsoft office tools automation is not supported on the server. Is there any alternative where I can create documents and make changes online?

Comment: "I have an application which creates word, excel and powerpoint applications"  huh?

Answer (score 0):

Office tools probably require MS office installed on your server. I guess this might be the solution to your problem.

Comment: How you can install MS office on the server? I have MS office installed in my system. Is that not sufficient?

Comment: As far as I understand, your server runs on Microsoft. Plug the CD and install Microsoft Office.

Answer (score 0):

When it is not possible to install Office on the server you can use [Open XML](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5124) to create and manipulate office documents. But you will have to rewrite your entire program for it to work I am afraid.

Comment: I have tried Open XML. I can create the files when the program is running on the server. But I tried it opening online but could not. May be i even dont know how to open it online. Is it possible to open it and make changes online?

Comment: there should be no problem opening and modifying files on the server. Have a look at [Open XML Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/bb265236) for some tutorials and code samples